# How to append text with OnClick method

Tags: android, string, onclick, append, toast

I would like to create a string whose components are appended once an ImageView is pressed.

I have an ImageView called imageView and named ImageView on clicking which I am appending a value to a string.
Finally when clicking on one button, I would like the string to show up with a Toast called out in the last Override.
I have, therefore, defined the string (named result), the button and the image, but I still get many errors, most notably I can't recall the "value1" when appending the String.

Any ideas?

```
Button button;
Button Click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
String result;
ImageView Imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

(...)

public class Program {
    public void main(String[] args) {

        final int value1 = 300;
        double value2 = 3.14;
        short value3 = 5;
        char value4 = 'A';

        // Create StringBuilder and add four values to it.
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(value2).append("\n");
        builder.append(value3).append("\n");
        builder.append(value4);

        // Display results.
        String result = builder.toString();
        System.out.println(result);


        public void onClick(View v) {

        Imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        builder.append(value1).append("\n");
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View V){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(Integer.parseInt(result)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get when you try to run it? Do you get the error when you try to append the values you have?

Comment: Hi SmiffyKmc, the value1 I am trying to append to the String named "result" through the Builder method, gives an error :/

Comment: Can you put up the error on this :)? I think I have an idea as to why it is giving an error as they are two different  types, string and an int. Arshadkazmi42 answer is how to do it but the error might be something small. What is the main error :)?

Comment: Hi again Smiffy, I am sending you a screenshot with the errors

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/50iaeobe5/
there you go. As you see I can't make the onClick method work and attach the "builder method" to append a whichever value. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay first when you are making an anonymous on click method you still have to put an on click inside that method. So where you have the new View.on click { HERE} You need the on click method. Cut out the append part and put in on click. Should auto complete. And then paste back in your append. Let me know then how you get on!

Comment: Hi SmiffyKmc, I am not sure I grasp all; do you, perhaps, mean something like 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

            Imageview.setOnClickListener(builder.append(value1).result.append("\n"));
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Main Activity Java class have somthing like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    Button click;
    String result ="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final int value1 = 300;
        final double value2 = 3.14;
        final short value3 = 5;
        final char value4 = 'A';

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //create the send intent
                Intent shareIntent =
                        new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

//set the type
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

//add a subject
                shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "Insert Subject Here");

//build the body of the message to be shared
                String shareMessage = "Insert message body here.";

//add the message
                shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        shareMessage);

//start the chooser for sharing
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.FinalString)));
            }
        });
        // Create StringBuilder and add four values to it.
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(value2).append("\n");
        builder.append(value3).append("\n");
        builder.append(value4);

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                builder.append(value1).append("\n");

            }
        });
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,builder.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


    }




}
```

i change Your XMl File To This iths better

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

### I Test It every things Fine

And Show  comment on Your Error [there](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13032515/)

Comment: Thanks @Saeed! I guess I can add further images in the following way, right?

ImageView imageview2 = (ImageView2) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
imageview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@ Override
public void onClick(View v) {
builder.append(value2).append("\n");
}
});


ImageView imageview3 = (ImageView3) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
imageview3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@ Override
public void onClick(View v) {
builder.append(value3).append("\n");


etcetera?

Comment: moreover, I don't know if it's clear, but I would like the final string to be the text to be shared through the SHARE INTENT method. I thought of the following code:

String result ="";     //at the very beginnig

result = builder.toString();    // after the toast method, so that the text is translate into string, that is the string "result"

and finally
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText.result));    //I would like the String so obtained to the text to be shared in the SHARE INTENT

Would that work out, in your mind, @Saeed?

Answer (score 1):

the frirst error for this line

```
 ImageView Imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

you can't use findById in your class block you have to use it in a function like onCreate so change your code .... your code have to
something like this

```
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String test=textView.getText().toString();
                textView.setText(test);

            }
        });
    }
```

just remember you have to add a textView to your xml file and set this id to tv_show;

Comment: Hi Saeed, yes, you are right, I forgot to check it.

Yet, I still can't make the whole code work. I set that on the click of the image the builder method should append "value1" to the String, but it does not work, how come?

Comment: if you can Send me your java and xml files i can find error and fix it for you

Comment: sure gladly! MainActivity.class http://pastebin.com/uPHrd5wu
content_main http://pastebin.com/yNMsFWFp
activity_main http://pastebin.com/pe4m09A4
It's still a draft, I know, but I am missing something of the basics :(

Answer (score 0):

Make `TextView` then `append();` :

in `XML`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="" />
```

in `Java`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        tv.append(value1 + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohamad, thanks but this works with a TextView tv. What if I wanted to append text to a String?

Comment: Didn't got what you mean?, TEXT IS `String`!

Comment: Sorry, I may have poorly expressed myself.
In your case you add "value1" to the TextView tv, correct?

In my case I have a String that will be composed of:
-value1 is I click on ImageView1
-value2 if I click on ImageView2
-value3 if I click on ImageView3

and so forth.

I though that the appen method would suit better the purpose, but I can't implement it, unfortunately :( any idea?

Comment: Is the app `ForceStop` when you tap on the `ImageView`?

Comment: nope, no traces of ForceStop :)
Would you like to receive the code through Pastebin? It would be way quicker this way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can append the string like this on button click

```
String stringName = "";
Imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    strigName = stringName + "New appended data";
}

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stringName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Hi Arshadkazmi, this would work well if I had only one append to do.
What if I had several appends to do?

Comment: Have a method you call with one value to be taken that is appended and have a value (string) final so you can set that value over and over which will append them together. Just call that method then in your on click :)

Comment: Sorry I can't show code, out and about at the moment!

Comment: @MDR, you can use the same for multiple appends, you just have to modify it as per your appending

Comment: ok, so Imagine a simple code like this
http://pastebin.com/LGrU7heb
Would I have problems if I clicked only the 1st and the 4th imageviews, for instance?
My point is, all the strings are name equally, wouldn't this give troubles to the code?

Comment: I couldnot get what you are asking? Can you explain what exactly you want to do? - In the sample code you gave. On click on IMage1 and 4 string will be appended with image1 string and image4 string